# WCF Rest does not serialize json, that expects an xml

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

we need to help us solve a problem in a WCF WebService, which returns the following message;

> Request error  The server encountered an error processing the request.
>   The exception message is' Failed to deserialize the object of type
>   System.String. The final element 'root' of the namespace '' was
>   expected. Found element 'UserEmail' from namespace ''. ' For more
>   information, see the server logs. The stack of exceptions is
>   monitored: 
>                in System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions
>   (XmlReaderDelegator reader, Boolean verifyObjectName,
>   DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)    in
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer.ReadObject
>   (XmlDictionaryReader reader, Boolean verifyObjectName)    in
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SingleBodyParameterDataContractMessageFormatter.ReadObject
>   (Message message)    in
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SingleBodyParameterMessageFormatter.DeserializeRequest
>   (Message message, Object [] parameters)    in
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DemultiplexingDispatchMessageFormatter.DeserializeRequest
>   (Message message, Object [] parameters)    in
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.UriTemplateDispatchFormatter.DeserializeRequest
>   (Message message, Object [] parameters)    in
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.DeserializeInputs
>   (MessageRpc & rpc)    in
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin
>   (MessageRpc & rpc)    in
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5
>   (MessageRpc & rpc)    in
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11
>   (MessageRpc & rpc)    in
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process (Boolean
>   isOperationContextSet)

We are sending the following json from the POSTMAN application:

```
{"EmailUser": "wilmer20@gmail.com", "PassUser": "123", "Password": "50625011800310141766399900001010000000010144332211"}
```

and returns the previous error.

If we add backslash :

```
{\ "EmailUsuario \": \ "wilmer20@gmail.com \", \ "PassUsuario \": \ "123 \", \ "Clave \": \ "5062501180031014176639990000101000000000014144332211 \"}
```

works correctly, but That makes it very difficult for you to consume the service to clients.

We need WCF to be able to correctly serialize the sent json.
The service is a WCF Rest, the code is Visual Basic.Net, framework 4.5, then the sample code:

```
    <OperationContract ()>
    <WebInvoke (Method: = "POST", UriTemplate: = "SendXML", RequestFormat: = 
    WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat: = WebMessageFormat.Json)>
    Function SendXML (json As String) As ClassJsonResponseSend
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

its a common mistake. you're method input is string. if you want the pure json you need to declare class like this and make it as your input:

```
[DataContract]
public class RootObject
{
    public string EmailUser { get; set; }
    public string PassUser { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

then something like this:

```
<OperationContract ()>
<WebInvoke (Method: = "POST", UriTemplate: = "SendXML", RequestFormat: = 
WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat: = WebMessageFormat.Json)>
Function SendXML (json As RootObject) As ClassJsonResponseSend
```

Note: why did you tag the question as c#? its clearly vb.net!!